# Прекращение действия, если мышка ушла

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, у меня всё просто:

```
$(function () {
    $(".view").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).find("div").animate({
            top: "0"
        });
    },

    function () {
        $(this).find("div").animate({
            top: "220px"
        });
    });

});
```

Но как отменить выполнение действия, если мышка ушла? Каждый раз элемент доходит до 0px, а хочется? чтобы он мог оборваться раньше, если курор уже в другом месте.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/stop/ - Останавливает все запущенные анимационные эффекты для всех указанных элементов.

Т.е. примерно так, если правильно понял суть задачи:

```
$(function() {
    $(".view").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find("div").stop(true,true).animate({
            top: "0"
            }); 
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find("div").stop(true,true).animate({
            top: "220px"
            }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: $(this).find("div").stop().animate({

Вот так заработало как надо! Благодарю!